# data.table setnames combined with regex

Tags: regex, r, data.table

I would like to rename each column in a data table based on a regex in an appropriate way.

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table("a_foo" = 1:2, "bar_b" = 1:2)
   a_foo bar_b
1:     1     1
2:     2     2
```

I would like to cut the "_foo" and "bar_" from the names. This classic line does the trick, but it also copies the whole table.

```r
names(DT) <- gsub("_foo|bar_", "", names(DT))
```

How can I do the same using `setnames()`? I have a lots of variables, so just writing out all of the names is not an option.

Comment: Try `setnames(DT, names(DT), gsub("_foo|bar_", "", names(DT)))`

Comment: @akrun you don't need the second argument in that expression

Comment: @eddi Yes, it should work, but I was following the one in the description to avoid any confusion. `setnames(x,old,new)`

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed. I should have tried this. Shall I delete my question now?

Comment: @janosdivenyi I can post this as a solution if you don't mind

Comment: @akrun Thanks, that would be fine for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try

```
setnames(DT, names(DT), gsub("_foo|bar_", "", names(DT)))
```

based on the usage in `?setnames` i.e. `setnames(x,old,new)`

Or as @eddi commented

```
setnames(DT, gsub("_foo|bar_", "", names(DT)))
```

Comment: Admittedly it's not obvious at first glance, but it actually is explained in `?setnames` if you read the descriptions under `old:` and `new:`, that `new` is optional.